# Awaiting Pop up in case of Multiple Popup Scenarios in Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a popup, let me call it "Warning Popup" with two buttons Yes and No and some event associated to it. Only after executing any one of the event, I want to display another popup (Success PopUp).
But currently, the Success Popup gets displayed over Warning Popup together, which does not allow me to click any of the YES/NO button  from Warning popup.

I have tried all possible ways :-
1) awaited the event associated with Popup
2) awaited the popup call
3) awaited the method which calls the popup fragment from it's respective class.
None of them worked.

```
if(some condition){
//
}
else{
ForceAcceptanceMessageFlag = true;
EventHandler<WarningEventArgs> forceAcceptanceEvent = (sender, e) => PerformForceAcceptanceAsync(tempGoodsItemsList);
string warningMsg = "SOME WARNING";
ShowWarningDialog(AppResources.Error, warningMsg, AppResources.OK, AppResources.Cancel,
 forceAcceptanceEvent, new EventHandler<WarningEventArgs>(NoButtonClicked)).Wait();
}

 private async void PerformForceAcceptanceAsync(ObservableCollection<FOHItem> looseGoodsItemsList)
{
   // some code
}

protected void NoButtonClicked(object sender, WarningEventArgs warningEventArgs)
{
    PopupNavigationService.Dismiss(ViewModelLocator.KEY_POPUP_WARNING);
}
```

Could someone help me with this scenario as I don't want to introduce some flags as there are a lot of other complex flows.

Comment: Set Task.delay(xxx) after you click the `Yes` button . Note that you should put it into main thread if you want to refresh the UI .